# enabling secondary display for 4.2.2

Tags: android, frameworks

I wanna use the secondary display API presentation and enable this feature in my build, but where to integrate and from where to start I am not able to figure out.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html will help you to start. It contains examples that helped me figure out what should be done and what should be taken care of.